# How can I change how IntelliJ's 'code reformat' breaks instantiations?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, reformat, reformatting

As IntelliJ's code reformat feature works, it breaks instantiation-expressions into more lines than is necessary.

Consider this expression:

```
File[] files = (chooser.getSelectedFiles().length == 0 ? chooser.getCurrentDirectory() : chooser.getSelectedFiles()[0]).listFiles();
```

This expression is too long to fit to one line. IntelliJ considers 100 characters to be max line length. This expression is 136 characters, not counting additional indentation for the method and class it is contained in.

Using IntelliJ's code reformat I end up with this:

```
File[]
    files =
    (chooser.getSelectedFiles().length == 0 ? chooser.getCurrentDirectory()
                                            : chooser.getSelectedFiles()[0]).listFiles();
```

What I find looks weird are the first two lines, where IntelliJ reformats this:

```
File[] files =
```

Into this:

```
File[] 
    files =
```

What can I do, and what settings do I change to end up with something like this instead?

```
File[] files =
    (chooser.getSelectedFiles().length == 0 ? chooser.getCurrentDirectory()
                                            : chooser.getSelectedFiles()[0]).listFiles();
```

Note: If I try to reformat again, after I manually change the two lines IntelliJ insisted on, back to one line, IntelliJ does not change it back.

Comment: You could avoid such problems by moving this ternary operator into a dedicated method. This would also make it clearer, what `files` contains and it is more readable.

Comment: Thanks for the tip , and I should probably have considered that before. I will see about changing it. But it still does not answer my question. This indentation-problem exists in other cases as well, I just used this expression as an example because it was the one that tipped the scales and made me ask StackOverflow. Thanks again!

Comment: That is why this is a comment and not an answer :P. I don't know what you need to edit to change that behavior. But I noticed that formatting style as well.